# What is the best strategy when using the Ghost Armor?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

What is the best strategy when using the Ghost Armor?  It is expensive, but is it best to create a "Predator-like" squad that can possibly dominate the game.  Due to the fact that the stealth ability shuts down at the end of the turn, I was not sure how effective this armor can be other than spying (spotting) enemies.

Answer (score 17):

The stealth ability doesn't shut down at the end of *your* turn, but the end of the enemy's turn.  This makes it extremely effective in several ways.

1. Scouting

   - I like to equip a support class with this armor.  The movement bonus from the armor, along with the base +3 movement distance, means he can move an insane amount per turn at 0 risk at all.
   - When you are cloaked, you will not trigger an AI reaction when exposing enemies, allowing you to get in 1 free shot while they are completely in the open.
   - If you have snipers with squad sight (and especially if they have double tap), they can easily take out entire enemy groups before they have a chance to react at all.
2. Aggressive Positioning

   - Getting my heavies in position while they are stealthed means the next turn, when the stealth wears off, they are very close to the enemy and can double tap and/or start off the fight with a rocket.
   - Assaults with shotguns also benefit greatly from being able to get in close to use rapid fire on a big enemy, taking it out in 1 turn.
3. Missions

   - You can safely deactivate bombs and rescue civilians while in complete stealth.
4. Oh crap moments can be preserved if you know your unit is heavily overexposed, you can make them go stealth and survive the turn.  Also its good for low health units to hide in stealth mode so they don't die.

This is all in addition to the other stuff armor comes with: the grappling hook (allowing your units to gain high elevation and tactical advantage), improved defense, and extra movement speeds.  Overall this is my favorite armor in the game.

Comment: another tip - heavy units with 'bullet swarm' can shoot - then cloak :)

Comment: Great tips but I don't know if I agree with #4, I hid and did not move an aliens still fired on my position.

Comment: @Mike aliens fired at your cloaked unit???

Comment: @spartacus yes, I moved, alert, cloaked, and [reload I think] but I did not move after the cloak.

Comment: hrmm... maybe its a glitch or something then, but I've never had aliens shoot at any of my cloaked units and I've beaten the game on classic difficulty so its probably not a tactics thing.

Comment: another good thing to be aware of: assaults in stealth will shoot on near alien using `Close Combat Specialist` perk and lose stealth.

Comment: I hope Mike is not referring to a Sectopod.  The fire based on where they last saw you.  Otherwise, it would be a glitch.

Comment: I've recently gained the ability to build ghost armours (it's my first game on xcom), and I'm starting to think it might make the game too easy. I quite liked the thrill of having my best soldier (psi sniper) shot down to 1 HP and finish the mission on sub-50% shots. Is there still a real challenge after getting such armours ?

Comment: @Greg nope, enemy within makes it even worse with unlimited stealth when you put in the right implants

Comment: @z' no it doesn't make the game too easy, or no there's no more real challenge ? I assume the latter, just want to make sure. Thanks

Comment: @greg You assume correctly.  Once you get ghost armor or mimetic skin the game becomes easy mode.

Answer (score 5):

One more useful use of Ghost Armor that has been very handy for me is to stabilize fallen soldiers.  I always give my support units Ghost Armor so they can cloak, get to exposed fallen units, and stabilize them.  Stabilizing and using medkits doesn't end the cloaking.  No matter how badly positioned a hurt or fallen unit is, a support unit can safely get to them.

Answer (score 2):

It's very handy for snipers that can't move a shoot in the same turn.

Ghost up your sniper then move to flank.

After the aliens turn your sniper gets to shoot first - or twice if you have Double Tap.

For newly discovered groups it helps to tab through to your sniper first at the start of the turn and let him have the first shot; after the snipers turn the aliens will react and often move into line of fire of other troops. If you let other troops move first they can alert the aliens and they could move out of line of sight of your sniper.

Comment: I would agree with this if Arcangel armour wasn't available very shortly afterwards... but it's another valid approach :-)

Answer (score 2):

Ghost armour makes room breaches trivial - just Ghost up and move all your troops into the room on one turn and get the aliens in a cross fire. Next turn they will uncloak after the aliens move and you have free shots.

If you ghost through any doors ensure non-cloaked soldiers won't been seen as you open the door